# Random array not working

Tags: php, arrays, random

When I generate an array of characters from a "valid character array", the final result is a random set of characters but IN ORDER. For example, I will get 34579abopxzBCJMSTXY.

```
include('db.php');
//$num= mt_rand();
$veces = $_POST['veces'];
$equipos = $_POST['equipos'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$salt = "oijahsfdapsf80efdjnsdjp";
function get_result(){
$valid_chars=array("0","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",     "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");

$result=array_rand($valid_chars, 20); //Cantidad de Caracteres
$result_str='';
foreach ($result as $value)
{
$result_str.=$valid_chars[$value];
}
return $result_str;
}
$results=array();

for ($i=0; $i<=2000; $i++)
{
array_push($results, get_result());
}

$results=array_unique($results);

$cont=0;
$results_str='';
foreach ($results as $value)
{
$cont++;
$results_str.=$value.'
';
// Add some salt
$salt = "oijahsfdapsf80efdjnsdjp";
$salt .= $value; //oijahsfdapsf80efdjnsdjp_Plus_RandomString
$value = $salt;  //Change the RandomString to contain our new salted pass
$value = md5($value);  //( cannot be reversed on a rainbow table as we have a secret salt also.. )
$db = new Database();
$ins_query = "INSERT INTO licensing(license, computers, state, description) VALUES('{$value}', '{$equipos}', '2', '{$description}')";    // query to insert value
$db->query($ins_query);
if ($cont>=$veces)
    {
    break;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
echo $results_str;
echo '</pre>';
```

PHP Information Version 5.3.3

Output Example:

```
1389adehtvwCEKMNQSUY
15bgmnpruwzAEFHTUVWY
159bcenqrswxzFKMNQUX
35bchstvwxyzEGKNQSUV
124789defgmvyDEHKNRT
5abefhjprsuwxCDMPQXY
```

Comment: It's time to stop using MD5 for cryptographic purposes. There are MUCH better alternatives out there. Use one of them instead.

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `shuffle(array)` on your `valid_char` variable to randomize all the elements
http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$valid_chars=array("0","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",     "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");

$result=array_rand($valid_chars, 20);
$i=0;
foreach ($result as $value)
{
$result[$i]=$valid_chars[$value];
$i++;
}


foreach ($result as $v) {
    echo "$v";
}
 echo "<br>";

shuffle($result);
foreach ($result as $v) {
    echo "$v";
}
```

this will echo

```
0128acfknqrsxCJMPQRS    //your string in "order"
PrMxR0k8nqJCQcS2sfa1
```